# How to understand recursion in Binary Tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I have started to learn Recursion , I seem to understand the concept , but at the same time I feel completely lost.

For eg, I was trying to solve find the ancestors of a given node in Binary Tree

My Tree:

```
      1
    /   \
   7     9
  / \   / \
 6  5  2   3
```

My code :

```
def findAns(node,target,ans):
        
    if node is None:
        return ans
    
    ans.append(node.data)
    if node == target:
        return ans[:-1] #return the list except the last item(whch will be the target node)

    ans = findAns(node.left,target,ans)
    
    ans = findAns(node.right,target,ans)

    del ans[-1] #Delete last node while backtracking
    
    
    return ans

ans=[]
findAns(root,target,ans) #target node is 5
print(ans)
print(ans[:-1])
```

OUTPUT :

```
[1,7,5]

[1, 7]
```

I am unable to understand the below questions,

1. When backtracking is completed for the entire tree, list 'ans' will be empty @ root position, how come I am able to get the value [1,7,5] in my list ?
2. when the if condition is satisfied , I return ans[:-1] , because I should not include the target node, but how come when I print 'ans' I am getting the target node as well ?
3. In the same 'if condition' , if I return ans instead of ans[:-1], y code doesn't work, I get back an empty 'ans' list, why is that ?

But to avoid the confusion I changed my code as mentioned below, I used a global variable . However I don't think it is efficient , any resource or material or explanations for my above question would be of great help to me. Thanks !

Code with Global variable:

```
_ans=[]
def findAns(node,target,ans):
    global _ans
    
    if node is None:
        return ans
    
    ans.append(node.data)
    if node == target:
        _ans.append(list(ans[:-1]))
        #return ans[:-1]

    ans = findAns(node.left,target,ans)
    
    ans = findAns(node.right,target,ans)

    del ans[-1]
    
    return ans

ans=[]
findAns(root,target,ans)
_ans[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You expected the root after backtracking returns empty list, well it does. The problem is the function returns the empty list but you don't catch it:

```py
res=findAns(root, target, ans)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

2. From question 1 you may still think printing `ans` will be the same as catching the return value, but when you return `ans[:-1]` you have already lost the original list you passed in. This is heavily related to list in python being mutable and `list[:-1]` will return a completely new list and modifying the new list won't affect the `ans` you first passed in. So after it returns a new list, the backtracking `ans = findAns(root.right, target, ans)` takes a new list, after that changing the 'new' `ans` won't change the 'old' `ans`(the one used to print)
3. If you change to `return ans` then it will print out empty list. The problem is every time you iterate through a step in the recursion you append a new node but at the same time you delete one last node, which results in add one and delete one being zero.